# WPF App runs slow only on my laptop

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, telerik

We have a team of about 5 developers that all work on the same wpf application. The app seems to run perfect and fast on everyones computer except mine. BTW we all have the same laptop with the same specs. I have looked at the processes running and can't seem to see anything out the ordinary. I have worked on this problem for days now and have spent hours trying to figure out why I'm having this problem. The app just seems to be very slow and choppy and is not smooth at all on my computer.

App Consist of:

- EntityFramework 5.0
- C# WPF / Telerik Controls

The other day I tried going into visual studio options and disabling JustMyCode and right after that, the app all of sudden worked perfect and fast. But the next time I ran it it was back to running slow again. Also I am the only one out of the developers who gets this error message in the output window:

```
    System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 : Unable to perform action because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for interactive control.; Action='Stop'; Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; Storyboard.HashCode='12079142'; Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; TargetElement='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'; TargetElement.HashCode='12079142'; TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard'
```

I honestly don't know what else to try. Seems like I tried everything. No one else in the office knows. I've even gone as far as reeinstalling visual studio **2012**. Any tips or advice on what could possibly happening is much appreciated.

Comment: I would install a fresh latest copy of the video driver.  All updates.  I assume you have defragged.

Comment: I would run the Performance Analysis on your laptop, save the results; and then run it on your colleague's laptop, and regression test those results against yours.

Comment: Same spec does not mean same computer.  I had a case once where they installed a wrong processor.  It was too fast for the mother board.  Proper processor fixed it.

Comment: Does it run ok outside the debugger, eg. Compile as release and run the executable, I have a heavily animated WPF app that runs like you describe when debugging in VS but runs perfect when running the exe outside of VS

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Unfortunately it still runs slow when I run the exe from the bin folder. I will try to compile as release and let you know, don't think it will make a diff.

Comment: @Blam I have installed the latest update for the driver already, no fix, I have defragged as well. I'm pretty sure regardless of the computer, my computer should be able to handle this app, especially since I seen it run correctly before.

Comment: I've ran performance analysis and seems wpfgf_v0400.dll is doing 50.46% Exclusive Samples doing most of the work. Any of yall know what this relates to?

Comment: Regarding the Binding error,you have Triggered that Storyboard in Trigger.EnterActions right,try to stop that Storyboard in Trigger.ExitActions.

Comment: @Ravuthasamy Yea see thats the thing. I don't see where we are using any storyboards at all in our app. I've done the majority of the xaml and sure that I don't have storyboards being ran.